# Is there a better way to control "Filling"?

Tags: plotting, regions, filling

I wrote the following code and it works well; however, along the horizontal axis observe the "reddish" line along the interval [0.25,0.75]. It is coming from the CC = line in the code. Is there a better way to use Filling so I don't see that "reddish" line but keep the red color for ftrng[x]?

```
funif[x_] := PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 1/2];
fbeta[x_] := PDF[BetaDistribution[5, 5], x];
ftrng[x_] := PDF[TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}, 1/2], x]
AA = Plot[{funif[x], If[0.25 <= x <= 0.75, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Black, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2, LightGray]];
BB = Plot[{fbeta[x], If[0.25 <= x <= 0.75, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2, LightGray]];
CC = Plot[{ftrng[x], If[0.25 <= x <= 0.75, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2, LightGray]];
DD = ListPlot[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Directive[Black]}, PlotRange -> All];
Show[AA, BB, CC, DD, PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {{0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 
    0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1}, Automatic}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 32}, 
 LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Calibri")]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) for `If[0.25 <= x <= 0.75, 0]` in each of the plots.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

funif[x_] := PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 1/2];
fbeta[x_] := PDF[BetaDistribution[5, 5], x];
ftrng[x_] := PDF[TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}, 1/2], x]
AA = Plot[{funif[x], If[0.25 <= x <= 0.75, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, {Thin, Gray}}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2, LightGray]];
BB = Plot[{fbeta[x], If[0.25 <= x <= 0.75, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Thin, Gray}}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2, LightGray]];
CC = Plot[{ftrng[x], If[0.25 <= x <= 0.75, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, {Thin, Gray}}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.2, LightGray]];
DD = ListPlot[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Directive[Black]}, PlotRange -> All];

Show[AA, BB, CC, DD, PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 1, 0.1], Automatic}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 32}, 
 LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Calibri")]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful!!! ... Many thank u's Bob

Answer (score 4):

`ImplicitRegion`+ `RegionPlot`.

```
Plot[{funif[x], fbeta[x], ftrng[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Prolog -> 
  RegionPlot[
    ImplicitRegion[{funif[x] <= y <= fbeta[x] || 
       funif[x] <= y <= ftrng[x] || 
       0 <= y <= funif[x] && .25 <= x <= .75}, {{x, 0, 1}, y}], 
    PlotStyle -> LightYellow][[1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank u cvgmt ... very tight and clever code ... thank u for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
funif[x_] := PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], x];
fbeta[x_] := PDF[BetaDistribution[5, 5], x];
ftrng[x_] := PDF[TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}, 1/2], x]

ffill[x_] := (UnitStep[x - 0.25] - UnitStep[x - 0.75]) Max[fbeta[x], 
   ftrng[x], funif[x]]

Plot[{
  fbeta[x], ftrng[x], funif[x]
  , ffill[x]
  }
 , {x, 0, 1.05}
 , Exclusions -> None
 , PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Red, None}
 , Ticks -> {Range[0.05, 1, 0.05], Automatic}
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , Filling -> 4 -> Axis
 , FillingStyle -> {Opacity[0.2, Yellow]}
 , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}
 , LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Calibri")
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks, Syed ... I like the way you separated out the 3 distributions upfront ... pg